# Hde This From The URL

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

how can I hide #myModal from displaying on the url? as of now everytime i click on the open modal

```
<a href="#myModal" class="open-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal">Load me</a>
```

in url ##myModal gets added which I do not want.

my current code

```
            `<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".open-modal").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            });
            });
            </script>`
```

Comment: `$(".open-modal").click(function() { .... return false; }`

Comment: Semantically, you should be using a `<button type=button'>` not an `<a>`.

Comment: With bootstrap data- attributes (`data-bs-toggle`) correctly configured you shouldn't need *any* javascript as the data- attributes and bootstrap.js will display the modal for you.

Answer (score 1):

never mind sorted it like this

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="open-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal">Advance Search</a>
```